# Can not store a new record in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this piece of code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(data){
      firebase.database().ref('Users').child('006').set({
        email: data.user.email,
        createdAt: data.user.createdAt
      }).then((data)=>{
        //success callback

        console.log('data ' , data);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        //error callback
        console.log('error ' , error)
      })
    }).catch(function(error) {
      //Handle error
    });
```

which is quite straight forward and what it basically does is to authenticate against Firebase systems and once it was finished, to store a new record in a realtime database that I've configured also there.

The issue is with this portion of code:

```
email: data.user.email,
createdAt: data.user.createdAt
```

if I leave it like this, it ever uses the 'data' values (which indeed are available at this stage) and doesn't create a new record in firebase. If I do it like this:

```
email: 'data.user.email',
createdAt: 'data.user.createdAt'
```

a new record is immediately added (of course, not with the actual values of email and createdAt but just the strings). I have tried to JSON.stringify/.toString() them but again with no success. I really don't know what I need to do in order to add the actual values to the JSON which is being passed to the **set** method.

And one side defect is that I am getting [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981)

The format and sample content of what is returned from

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

in the 'then' arguments list is:

```
   {
   "user":{
      "uid":"some_user_id",
      "displayName":null,
      "photoURL":null,
      "email":"hshy@bshs.hs",
      "emailVerified":false,
      "phoneNumber":null,
      "isAnonymous":false,
      "providerData":[
         {
            "uid":"hshy@bshs.hs",
            "displayName":null,
            "photoURL":null,
            "email":"hshy@bshs.hs",
            "phoneNumber":null,
            "providerId":"password"
         }
      ],
      "apiKey":"some_api_key",
      "appName":"[DEFAULT]",
      "authDomain":"sub-dom.firebaseapp.com",
      "stsTokenManager":{
         "apiKey":"some_api_key",
         "refreshToken":"some_JWT_token",
         "accessToken":"some_JWT_token",
         "expirationTime":1541582223251
      },
      "redirectEventId":null,
      "lastLoginAt":"1541577292000",
      "createdAt":"1541577292000"
   },
   "credential":null,
   "additionalUserInfo":{
      "providerId":"password",
      "isNewUser":true
   },
   "operationType":"signIn"
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your `data.user.email` and `data.user.createdAt` are empty/don't have a value. Firebase will only store keys that have values, so if those values are empty that would explain what you see.

Comment: I've updated my answer. As you can see, These values are not empty/null/undefined. They actually have a value and are available in the result from the auth operations but for some reason I can not use them. This is really strange.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. 
There is an issue in the code with the way you're retrieving the info for storage, which is why it turns out `undefined` and doesn't store.
It would be something like:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(authResponse){
      firebase.database().ref('Users').child('006').set({
        email: authResponse.user.email,
        createdAt: authResponse.user.metadata.creationTime
      }).then((data)=>{
        //success callback

        console.log('data ' , data);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        //error callback
        console.log('error ' , error)
      })
    }).catch(function(error) {
      //Handle error
    });
```

Here are the references for the auth method - [firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
and for the return object - [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User)

Comment: I really can not see the difference. I mean, you just substitute 'data' with 'user' in the 'then' arguments list. The bahavior is exactly the same. I will update my question to see what is returned (and in what format) from the auth endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

What turns out to be the issue is the access level to the:

```
createdAt: data.user.createdAt
```

As you can see in my question, it is available there in the JSON, but for some reason I can not get its value and this is what causes the lack of new record and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981). I will upvote the @Code.Warrior's answer because it is in the right the direction but the way I got the create date is as follows:

```
.then(function(authResponse){
          firebase.database().ref('Users').child(authResponse.user.uid).set({
            email: authResponse.user.email,
            createdAt: authResponse.user.metadata.creationTime
          }).then((data)=>{
            //success callback

            console.log('data ' , data);
          }).catch((error)=>{
            //error callback
            console.log('error ' , error)
          })
        }).catch(function(error) {
          //Handle error
        });
```

It is one level further nested.